# React does not return keyCode from key event

Tags: reactjs

I set up a basic input field and attached a keyDown event on it. I have noticed it does not return the keyCode in the event?

```
export default class ShortTermGoals extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
    }

    getVal(event){
        console.log(event)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="input-group">
                <input type="text" onKeyDown={ ()=> { this.getVal(event) } } />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `event` in the callback aswell.

`onKeyDown={ (event)=> { this.getVal(event) }`

**However**, using arrow functions inside JSX may decrease your app dynamics, it's suggested to avoid using lambdas there. What's more - event listeners are passing `event` by default, so you don't have to use lambas nor pass any argument:

`onKeyDown={this.getVal}`

Also remember to use arrow functions aswell in class methods:

```
getVal = (event) => {
  console.log(event)
}
```